# Do I need to include the 'this' when using a property name in a closure?

Tags: c#, closures

I'm using a list of Actions to store an undo history for an object.  Let's say I have a property of my object called myChildObject and it's being mutated by a method call, so I want to store the undo action where I would mutate it back to it's current value:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
    }

    private readonly List<Action> m_undoActions = new List<Action>();

    private SomeObject myChildObject { get; set; }

    public void ChangeState()
    {
        m_undoActions.Add(() => myChildObject.UndoChangeState());
        myChildObject.ChangeState();
    }
}
```

Looking at the lambda expression, is the reference to myChildObject (the object) passed or is the reference to 'this' passed.  Do I need to use 'this' to preface it?  Do I need to make a copy of the 'this' reference to a local variable first?

Thanks for helping me understand this closure stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no more need to explicitly designate a member as an instance member within a lambda than there is outside of the lambda.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my question to make it clearer.  I'm trying to figure out what's passed into the closure: a reference to 'this' or a reference to the child object itself?

Comment: What you have now is not a true closure. This will just cause an instance method to be created instead of a static method.

Comment: If I wanted to make it a true closure, would I create a local variable, like: var me = this; and then call me.myChildObject.UndoChangeState() in the lambda?

Comment: That would create a closure, yes. But that would add (needless) complexity to the generated code over what the current example creates.

Comment: You're confusing me.  Aren't closures and instance methods orthogonal?  If it compiles down to an instance method, it could still use a closure if I wanted to pass another variable from ChangeState into myChildObject.ChangeState, right?

Comment: The two are not related. A closure (as you correctly guess) means that you're involving a local variable in the anonymous function. This has the side-effect of creating a compiler generated class.